# How can strip out \x00 bytes from a text document

Tags: python, filter, byte, strip

I have an input stream from an unit and I want to filter out the bytes '\x00'. Those empty bytes appear only printing the variable. For example, I want to filter out \x00 from the following variable.

```
example = b'\n\x00[\x007\x000\x004\x005\x001\x009\x004\x009\x000\x006\x008\x004\x002\x00]\x00 \x00-\x00 \x00D\x00S\x00I\x00 \x00-\x00 \x00R\x00e\x00s\x00p\x00o\x00n\x00s\x00e\x00'
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `filter` with a `None` filter (removes falsy elements) and force rebuilding of a `bytes` object:

```
example = b'\n\x00[\x007\x000\x004\x005\x001\x009\x004\x009\x000\x006\x008\x004\x002\x00]\x00 \x00-\x00 \x00D\x00S\x00I\x00 \x00-\x00 \x00R\x00e\x00s\x00p\x00o\x00n\x00s\x00e\x00'
result = bytes(filter(None,example))
```

result

```
b'\n[7045194906842] - DSI - Response'
```

(the generic answer is `result = bytes(x for x in example if x != character_code)`, in that case we generally don't use `filter` because it would require a `lambda`)

Answer (score 1):

You could just try using `replace()` as follows:

```
print(example.replace(b'\0', b''))
```

This displays:

```
b'\n[7045194906842] - DSI - Response'
```

The text might be in `utf-16` format so the following would convert it to a string:

```
print(example.decode('utf-16'))
```